# Как использовать JOIN в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Как использовать JOIN?. В инете я не нашёл чёткого и вразумительного описания. Есть две таблицы:

1) `authors` (авторы)
с полями:

```
`author_id` (auto increment),
`fio`,
`e-mail`,
`his_password`,
`raiting`.
```

2) `articles` (статьи)
с полями:

```
`article_no` (auto increment),
`author_id`,
`title`,
`text`.
```

Когда php-скрипт берёт из второй таблицы статью по её article_no (он передаётся в адресе страницы методом GET), он должен также получить ещё и ФИО автора и его рейтинг из первой таблицы. Это можно сделать двумя запросами:

```
$query1 = mysql_query ("SELECT `author_id`, `title`, `text` FROM `articles` WHERE `article_no` = '$article_no_from_get'");
$result1 = mysql_fetch_array ($query1)

$query2 = mysql_query ("SELECT `fio`, `raiting` FROM `authors` WHERE `author_id` = '$result1 [author_id]'");
```

Однако более рационально было бы объединить эти два запроса в один с помощью JOIN. Как это сделать?

С уважением, В.Иванов

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT articles.author_id, articles.title, articles.text, authors.fio, authors.raiting FROM articles JOIN ON articles.author_id=authors.author_id WHERE articles.article_no = '$article_no_from_get'
```

Примерно так, если я не ошибаюсь

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про join в [wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)), там на простых примерах рассмотрены базовые вещи.