# mysql select из 2-х таблиц

Tags: mysql, запрос, select

Есть первая таблица (ocenka) в которой содержится ид сотрудника и  ид его руководителя.
Есть вторая таблица (sotr) где содержатся фамилии этих людей.
Это то что у меня получилось, но не понимаю как расширить до вывода Фамилии и сотрудника и его руководителя.

```
SELECT ocenka.id_sotr, sotr.fio FROM ocenka, sotr Where ocenka.id_sotr=sotr.id
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как использовать JOIN в MySQL?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/41080/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-join-%d0%b2-mysql)

Comment: там совсем не то

Comment: Покажите структуру ваших таблиц

Comment: Покажите структуру БД, полученный результат и желаемый результат запроса.

Comment: http://i91.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0922/a1/df40aa41d9604fb37ba931000698e4a1.png это оценка

Comment: http://i91.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0922/ba/664809c3396cf795305cc0036317b2ba.png это sotr

Comment: Нужно выбрать данные в виде ID - ФИО сотрудника - ФИО руководителя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю как у вас поле ид руководителя называется в таблице ocenka, но если бы оно называлось id_rucovoditel, то тогда так

```
SELECT 
    ocenka.id_sotr as "ИД"
   ,sotrS.fio  as "фИО сотрудика"
   ,sotrR.fio as "ФИО руководителя"
FROM 
    ocenka oc
    join sotr sotrS on oc.id_sotr=sotrS.id
    join sotr sotrR on oc.id_rucovoditel=sotrR.id
```

А если серьезно, Вам нужно почитать sql для чайников))) так как это самый базовый вопрос)).

Comment: Не получается с вашим запросом. `SELECT dekad_ocenka.id_sotr, sotr_S.fio as "ФИО_С", dekad_dolgnost.name, sotr_R.fio AS "ФИО Р", dekad_ocenka.ocen_itog FROM dekad_ocenka, dekad_dolgnost, JOIN sotr sotr_S on oc.id_sotr=sotr_S.id JOIN sotr sotr_R on oc.id_ruk=sotr_R.id`

Comment: ругается `right syntax to use near 'JOIN sotr sotr_S on oc.id_sotr=sotr_S.id JOIN sotr sotr_R on oc.id_ruk=sotr_R.id' at line 1 `

Comment: @maix Возьмите запрос без изменений, как в ответе. Скопируйте в блокнот или там в ворд. Дальше поиском и заменой заменяйте по одному - имена таблиц, имена полей...  тогда (если опять не накосячите) получится.

Comment: И ещё - в исходном вопросе не было ни полслова про должности. Посему кивать на проблемы в неозвученной задаче - некорректно.

Comment: @heff Выдает вот так. SELECT dekad_ocenka.id_sotr as "ИД" ,sotrS.fio as "фИО сотрудика" ,sotrR.fio as "ФИО руководителя" FROM dekad_ocenka oc join dekad_sotr sotrS on oc.id_sotr=sotrS.id join dekad_sotr sotrR on oc.id_ruk=sotrR.id LIMIT 0, 25 Ответ MySQL: Документация #1054 - Unknown column 'dekad_ocenka.id_sotr' in 'field list'

Comment: я писал SELECT ocenka.id_sotr as "ИД" у вас SELECT dekad_ocenka.id_sotr as "ИД" ,sotrS.fio as "фИО сотрудика", dekad_ откуда взялось? в общем если вы правильно все поменяете, то все заработает.

Comment: @heff это названия таблиц. Просто сюда полностью не стал вставлять

Comment: @heff http://i91.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0922/25/1f6d0ad2a85fd8c784c956c2d341ea25.jpg Что я сделал не так, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: dekad_ocenka.id_sotr as "ИД"  выводит из таблицы dekad_ocenka поле id_sotr . В вашей таблице dekad_ocenka  нет колонки id_sotr

Comment: @heff как нет, на средней картинке 3-я по счету

Comment: значит не в той базе выполняете или не ту картинку сфотографироали

Comment: @heff http://i91.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0922/e2/55f6a71a3418d3f1c4cecf5db73418e2.png Вроде бы все там делаю

Comment: dekad_ocenka.id_sotr поменяйте на oc.id_sotr потому что в блоке from таблице dekad_ocenka дан алиас oc

Comment: Вот оно что! Спасибо! А все не мог понять что за "ОС" И в гугле уже поглядел, нет вроде такой команды

Comment: не за что, но вам тут гугл не сильно поможет, советую прочитать книжку по sql, заточенную под ту бд на которой пишите.